# whiat is different between function conj(x) and method x.conj() python

Tags: python

I know `conj(x)` and `x.conj()` do the same thing, but what is the main difference?. Is that we can do any function as method such as `sum(x)` written as `x.sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your own class you can define a method to use the built in function:

```
class Example(list):
    def sum(self):
        return sum(self)

x = Example((1,2,3))
print(x.sum())
```

Although there is no direct way to make this functionality available to built in types like `list` itself.